# What is P***Y? Is it giving a bad impression?

Tags: meaning, expressions, figurative-language

I saw movie of [this post](https://twitter.com/Salaam_D_Nakba/status/795985582925066240?s=09). I found this sentence:

> And bragged about grabbing women by the P***Y

What's P***Y? I think it is not a good expression... (Because I hear bleep censor while the man is talking.)

Comment: Based on the answer so far, this question seems to be about censorship, not about learning English (at best asking to fill in the correct word). More research would have been nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"P***Y" is a censored form of the word "pussy," a vulgar term for the vagina. Refer to this definition:

> [**pussy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pussy)
>   *vulgar slang* A woman's genitals.

Use of asterisks (`*`) to censor words is common, possibly in part because they don't serve any purpose in English writing (unlike ampersands, colons, solidi, etc.). The intention is to avoid actually writing the word out while still making it clear what word is meant to be there.

In television broadcasting, vulgar words and profanities are often censored because of a [watershed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(broadcasting)) or "safe harbour" – a restriction on what content can be televised before a certain time (21:00 in the UK, 22:00 in the US). It might also be that the channel doesn't want to be associated with the use of vulgar terms and profanities, as that can reduce the size of their audience and dissuade advertisers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a coarse expression in English:

> Grab a man by the balls, and their hearts and minds will follow.

In this expression, "balls" refers to a man's testicles.  "Balls" metaphorically refers to a man's manliness and ability to father children.  "Heart" refers to a person's courage and persistence against adversity.  "Mind" refers to a person's thoughts.

In *[Small Gods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062237373)*, Terry Pratchett translated this expression into dog-Latin, and then [back into English](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Discworld#Small_Gods):

> *Cuius testiculos habes, habeas cardia et cerebellum.*
>   When you have their full attention in your grip, their hearts and minds will follow.

*Small Gods* was a humorous fantasy book with historical and religious themes.  It is widely read by both children and adults.

The original post refers to a Donald Trump quote (in the context of two guys joking about life and seduction):

> Grab 'em by the pussy, and their hearts and minds will follow.

As LMS explains, "pussy" refers to a woman's genitals.

Comment: While more answers are a good thing, I don't think your answer is correct. A quote from Donald Trump with additional context is "When you're a star they let you do it. You can do anything." I think what Trump was saying was less metaphorical and more about actual, literal groping.

Comment: @LMS -- With a good metaphor, the listener can imagine the story being true both literally and figuratively.

Comment: The phrase "If you've got them by the balls, their hearts and minds will follow" has unclear origins but is typically accredited to Teddy Roosevelt, although there's no evidence of him saying it.  Having said that, this answer seems to be the only place suggesting Trump was basing his phase on it - everyone else seems to be understanding it to be a little more 'direct' than that.

Comment: The New York Times’ page [Transcript: Donald Trump’s Taped Comments About Women](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/08/us/donald-trump-tape-transcript.html) gives a recording of the conversation and a transcript (with some gaps because of audio/intelligibility issues). According to that, Trump said, “… You know, I’m automatically attracted to beautiful — I just start kissing them. It’s like a magnet. Just kiss. I don’t even wait. And when you’re a star, they let you do it. You can do anything Grab ’em by the pussy. … You can do anything.” Maybe hyperbole, but it doesn’t sound like a metaphor.

Comment: You can also see/hear the audio (without the transcript) at http://nyti.ms/2dGHiKE, which is a tiny URL for https://www.nytimes.com/video/us/politics/100000004698018/donald-trumps-lewd-comments-about-women.html?smid=pl-share.   The phrases that I quoted above start around timestamp 1:10.